# How to define dsl content from file in Jenkins Job Builder yaml file with pipeline style

Tags: jenkins, dsl

jjb file content:

```
- job:
name: test_job
project-type: pipeline
dsl: |
  stage('ok') {{
    sh "echo 'Hello World'"
  }}
```

Now I've a long content should be written in `dsl` block. Is there a way to inject dsl content from a file?

Comment: I know the content can be specified from online repo like git. And is there a way to get it from a local file?

Comment: you can try   dsl:  !include-rwa: {appname}.groovy